# Bucket sort to find nearby almost duplicates

Tags: python

I am working on problem  [Contains Duplicate III - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/contains-duplicate-iii/)

> Given an array of integers, find out whether there are two distinct indices *i* and *j* in the array such that the **absolute** difference between **nums[i]** and **nums[j]**is at most *t* and the **absolute** difference between *i* and *j* is at most *k*.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input: nums = [1,2,3,1], k = 3, t = 0
> Output: true
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input: nums = [1,0,1,1], k = 1, t = 2
> Output: true
> ```
>
> **Example 3:**
>
> ```
> Input: nums = [1,5,9,1,5,9], k = 2, t = 3
> Output: false
> ```

Read a bucket sort solution from the discussion area

```
class Solution2:
    def containsNearbyAlmostDuplicate(self, nums, k, t):
        if t < 0: return False
        lookup = {}
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            b_idx = nums[i] // (t+1) 
            if b_idx in lookup:
                return True
            if b_idx - 1 in lookup and abs(nums[i] - lookup[b_idx - 1]) < t+1:
                return True
            if b_idx + 1 in lookup and abs(nums[i] - lookup[b_idx + 1]) < t+1:
                return True
            lookup[b_idx] = nums[i] 
            if i >= k: del lookup[nums[i-k] // (t+1)]
        return False
```

The explaination

> The idea is like the bucket sort algorithm. Suppose we have consecutive buckets covering the range of nums with each bucket a width of (t+1). If there are two item with difference <= t, one of the two will happen:
>       (1) the two in the same bucket
>       (2) the two in neighbor buckets

I know the logic of bucket sort, but have no ideas how this solution works.

I think, it is necessary to compare between all the values with range of width, but the solution only compare the same bucket and the adjacent bucket,

`del lookup[num[i-k]`, I cannot figure out what the purpose of this manipulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First Question:
why only compare the same bucket and the adjacent bucket?

As author said, there are two situations if `(a, b)` is a valid pair:

> (1) the two in the same bucket
>   (2) the two in neighbor buckets

If `b - a <= t` then only two situations as above said, you can understand it by bucket examples here:

> <--a-- t+1 ---b-><----- t+1 -----> in same bucket
>   <----- t+1 --a--><---b- t+1 -----> in neighbor buckets

`Bucket` is used here is because we want to divide the range into pariticular width, and decrease the compare times. This is a method of trading space for time.

---

Second Question: why `del lookup[num[i-k]`?

Because the second restrict is the difference index `i`, `j` should at most k.

So in `for i in range(len(nums)):` we should remove the previous index j from bucket, if `i - j == k`. And difference equal k is included, so we should remove after logic.

If you don't do that, you will find the pairs which `abs(nums[i]-nums[j])<=t`, but `abs(i-j)>t`

---

I hope I make it clear, and comment if you have further questions. : )

---

By the way, an advice: if you are confused or stucked, you can go through a example by print or debug, you will be more clear, especially for corner case.

Comment: I'm really appreciate for your support, I'm new guy here less than two weeks, and I enjoy helping others, and enhance my skills and communication ability at same time. By the way, forgive for my poor english : ) @l'L'l

Comment: amazing, cannot believe you are new.

Comment: Actually I have got a lot of help from stackoverflow when I googled. But didn't sign up before. : ) @Alice

Comment: I tried best to wrap my mind around but still unclear `if i >=k`, since `i-j==k` is included, why it is not 'if i > k`?

Comment: `if i >= k` is used to prevent negative index, if i < k, nums[i-k] will have invalid index. @Alice

Comment: by the way, if you are a LeetCoder, and want to enhance your algorithm, maybe you can watch my github, I am summerizing the [code templates and examples](https://github.com/recnac-itna/Code_Templates) recently. maybe it will help you.

Comment: oh, I got it, about the special case `i ==k`. if reverse the sequence of `lookup[b_idx] = nums[i]  if i >= k: del lookup[nums[i-k] // (t+1)]` , it should be ` if i > k:... lookup..`

Comment: I think you can not change the order of these two statements, and it is not equivalence of these two situation.

Comment: thank you, I read the solution again days later, still confused with why `i >=k` rather than `i > k`. delighted and surprised to read your answer.

Comment: an advice: if you are confused, you can go through a example by print or debug, you will be more clear, especially for corner case.

Comment: 收到, 将您添加到收藏夹了,逐个看回答过的问题.

Comment: @Alice 受人以鱼，不如授人以渔，你可以看我github上总结的代码模板，以及筛选的leetcode最典型例题和解法，这样提升会比较快，老铁加油